# how to post facebook fan page wall

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I tried to post image in facebook fan page.

I am using below code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/facebookPage_ID/photos"
                              parameters:@{ @"url": @"https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/378/378006-bigthumbnail.jpg",}
                              HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // Insert your code here
}];
```

Current image posts to facebook page successfully but image "did not post in facebook page wall" is shown in visitor post.

I want to show image in facebook page wall.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a Page Access Token instead of a User Access Token:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

The steps:

- Get a User Token with the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions
- Use `/page-id?fields=access_token` to get a Page Token for a specific Page

Comment: how to get page access token please help.

Comment: it is explained in the docs, i have added another link and the steps to get a page token

Comment: ok i got page access token but now how to use this access token with post image?

Comment: find "tokenString" in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKGraphRequest/

Comment: NSDictionary *params =
                    @{
                        @"access_token":Token,
                            @"url":strImageURL,
                            @"message": message,
                    };

Comment: use "tokenString", not "parameters", as you can read in the docs. look at the link in my comment.

Comment: bro i am new in iOS.. i do not understood what you say and how to use tokenString.

Comment: i have never used it, but according to the docs you can just use "tokenString" like you did with "parameters". or try to add the access_token as a normal parameter. do some testing.

Comment: why the downvote? whoever downvoted, please tell me why so i can improve my answer. it is definitely the issue though.